# Make a grid of divs fill their assigned space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I'm new to CSS and fluid grids. I'm following this tutorial here:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/fluid-grids-in-responsive-design/

Following the suggestion I read there, I had a css file auto generated for me. I wanted to create a header with three parts, where each part takes up 1/3 screen width. However, it looks like the widths of the divs are collapsing to fit the content as seen here:

[image: Screenshot]

How do I make the divs fill the ~33% like I want them to?

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link href="testcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="containter_12">

    <div class="grid_4">

       <img src="logo.png"/> 

    </div>

    <div class="grid_4">

        <b>ACPL Wellness</b>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4">

        <b>Home</b>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
/* Containers
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.container_12 {
    width: 92%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
}

/* Grid >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
        font-size: 2em;
}

/* Grid >> Children (Alpha ~ First, Omega ~ Last)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.alpha {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.omega {
    margin-right: 0;
}

/* Grid >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


.container_12 .grid_1 {
    width:6.333%;
}

.container_12 .grid_2 {
    width:14.667%;
}

.container_12 .grid_3 {
    width:23.0%;
}

.container_12 .grid_4 {
    width:31.333%;
}

.container_12 .grid_5 {
    width:39.667%;
}

.container_12 .grid_6 {
    width:48.0%;
}

.container_12 .grid_7 {
    width:56.333%;
}

.container_12 .grid_8 {
    width:64.667%;
}

.container_12 .grid_9 {
    width:73.0%;
}

.container_12 .grid_10 {
    width:81.333%;
}

.container_12 .grid_11 {
    width:89.667%;
}

.container_12 .grid_12 {
    width:98.0%;
}



/* Prefix Extra Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


.container_12 .prefix_1 {
    padding-left:8.333%;
}

.container_12 .prefix_2 {
    padding-left:16.667%;
}

.container_12 .prefix_3 {
    padding-left:25.0%;
}

.container_12 .prefix_4 {
    padding-left:33.333%;
}

.container_12 .prefix_5 {
    padding-left:41.667%;
}

.container_12 .prefix_6 {
    padding-left:50.0%;
}

.container_12 .prefix_7 {
    padding-left:58.333%;
}

.container_12 .prefix_8 {
    padding-left:66.667%;
}

.container_12 .prefix_9 {
    padding-left:75.0%;
}

.container_12 .prefix_10 {
    padding-left:83.333%;
}

.container_12 .prefix_11 {
    padding-left:91.667%;
}



/* Suffix Extra Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


.container_12 .suffix_1 {
    padding-right:8.333%;
}

.container_12 .suffix_2 {
    padding-right:16.667%;
}

.container_12 .suffix_3 {
    padding-right:25.0%;
}

.container_12 .suffix_4 {
    padding-right:33.333%;
}

.container_12 .suffix_5 {
    padding-right:41.667%;
}

.container_12 .suffix_6 {
    padding-right:50.0%;
}

.container_12 .suffix_7 {
    padding-right:58.333%;
}

.container_12 .suffix_8 {
    padding-right:66.667%;
}

.container_12 .suffix_9 {
    padding-right:75.0%;
}

.container_12 .suffix_10 {
    padding-right:83.333%;
}

.container_12 .suffix_11 {
    padding-right:91.667%;
}



/* Push Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


.container_12 .push_1 {
    left:8.333%;
}

.container_12 .push_2 {
    left:16.667%;
}

.container_12 .push_3 {
    left:25.0%;
}

.container_12 .push_4 {
    left:33.333%;
}

.container_12 .push_5 {
    left:41.667%;
}

.container_12 .push_6 {
    left:50.0%;
}

.container_12 .push_7 {
    left:58.333%;
}

.container_12 .push_8 {
    left:66.667%;
}

.container_12 .push_9 {
    left:75.0%;
}

.container_12 .push_10 {
    left:83.333%;
}

.container_12 .push_11 {
    left:91.667%;
}



/* Pull Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


.container_12 .pull_1 {
    left:-8.333%;
}

.container_12 .pull_2 {
    left:-16.667%;
}

.container_12 .pull_3 {
    left:-25.0%;
}

.container_12 .pull_4 {
    left:-33.333%;
}

.container_12 .pull_5 {
    left:-41.667%;
}

.container_12 .pull_6 {
    left:-50.0%;
}

.container_12 .pull_7 {
    left:-58.333%;
}

.container_12 .pull_8 {
    left:-66.667%;
}

.container_12 .pull_9 {
    left:-75.0%;
}

.container_12 .pull_10 {
    left:-83.333%;
}

.container_12 .pull_11 {
    left:-91.667%;
}




/* Clear Floated Elements
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* http://sonspring.com/journal/clearing-floats */

.clear {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

/* http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/02/05/lessons-learned-concerning-the-clearfix-css-hack */

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}

.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Is your CSS file path correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is much easier then I initially thought! Read the first div it's class definition: it says containter_12 instead of container_12. That should fix it!

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes you just need another set of eyes to see stuff like this!

Answer (score 0):

I try to use this CSS reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ in every webpage I build. This helps me to avoid a lot of these problems. Can you try this first?

When it does not solve your problem, try using Google Chrome and its Inspect element feature to find what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the width of .grid_4

Try adding this in your CSS file

```
.grid_4 {
    width: 33%;
}
```

If the div on the very right (the one that says 'home') appears underneath the other two, reduce the width until they all fit on the screen.

Comment: I have defined that (or at least the generator did). if you scroll down you can see it's set to 31.333%